# there is a way to execute internal command (dot command) of Sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, typeorm

I would like to execute dot command (command sqlite begin by "." character and not SQL concept) for managing my database into my Electron project.

Now I use TypeORM for working with my table. But If I want to work with another thing about entity, I don't find anything for that.

Is there anything (module, library, ...) into Electron/Node world it can execute a dot internal command sqlite3 like this :

[Sqlite3 internal dot Command](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_commands.htm)

Comment: Which dot commands? There's probably equivalents via a SQLite library.

Comment: I would like to execute those command sqlite : .databases .dump .import .backup .schema .stats and .timer